# Multiple Rex Expressions

Tags: regex, splunk, rex

I'm using the rex expressions below to search for the following fields in my raw data:

Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Address Line 3
Address Line 4, and
Postcode

```
| rex "Address Line 1=(?<address1>[^,]*)"  
| rex "Address Line 2=(?<address2>[^,]*)"  
| rex "Address Line 3=(?<address3>[^,]*)"  
| rex "Address Line 4=(?<address4>[^,]*)"  
| rex "Postcode=(?<postcode>[^,]*)"
```

As you can see by the expression, each of these fields is then assigned a variable so for Address Line 1, the variable is address1, Address Line 2 is 'address2' and so on.

As you will also no doubt see, the above expression contains multiple rex expressions, could someone perhaps tell me please, is there a way to combine these into one rex expression.

Answer (score 1):

The first example on page https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/SearchReference/Rex shows how to extract multiple fields with a single `rex` command. If your `_raw` is multiline, use `\n` or `\r` as appropriate.
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/Knowledge/AboutSplunkregularexpressions

Answer (score 1):

you simply put several group match in your regex. Here is an example:

`|   rex field=_raw "\"SubjectId\":\"(?P<User>[^\"]*)\".*\"GrantType\":\"(?P<GrantType>\w*)\".*\"Category\":\"(?P<Category>\w+)\".*\"Name\":\"(?P<desc>[^\"]*)\".*\"TimeStamp\":\"(?P<TimeStamp>[^\"]*)\".*\"RemoteIpAddress\":\"(?P<IP>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\"" |`

of course, this requires to know the order of the fields in advance, which is not required when chaining several 'rex' expressions in your search.

I do find it easier for complex example to first put a few lines in [regex101.app](https://regex101.com/) for instance to validate the expression (I'm using the local installed app, but the website works)

#### EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENT

If all your addresses are separated by comma as your regular expression seems to show:

|   rex field=_raw "(?P<addr1>[^,]*),(?P<addr2>[^,]*),(?P<addr3>[^,]*),(?P<addr4>[^,]*),(?P<postalcode>.*)"

If the separator is something else, just replace the character in each group.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30794937)